# Remove <br> tags from a parsed Beautiful Soup list?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm currently getting into a for loop with all the rows I want:

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(pageurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
tables = soup.find("td", "bodyTd")
for row in tables.findAll('tr'):
```

At this point, I have my information, but the

```
<br />
```

tags  are ruining my output.

What's the cleanest way to remove these?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
for e in soup.findAll('br'):
    e.extract()
```

Comment: Well that's definitely the way to go then!

Comment: This works but it extracts any text between the br, so it's not going to only remove the extra br, you won't be able to separate your text with br because it will remove it

Comment: In my case, this solution got rid of the text surrounding the br tags as well, so I used `e.replace_with(' ')` to replace br tags with a space.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to translate the `<br />`'s to newlines, do something like this:

```
def text_with_newlines(elem):
    text = ''
    for e in elem.recursiveChildGenerator():
        if isinstance(e, basestring):
            text += e.strip()
        elif e.name == 'br':
            text += '\n'
    return text
```

Answer (score 3):

replace  tags at the start with a space
Beautiful soup also accepts the .read() on the urlopen object so this should work - - -

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(pageurl)
page_text=page.read()
new_text=re.sub('</br>',' ',page_text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(new_text)
tables = soup.find("td", "bodyTd")
for row in tables.findAll('tr'):
.....
```

the re.sub replaces the br tag with a whitespace

Comment: for br attributes just replace in re.sub('</br.+>',' ',page_text)

Comment: If you're certain that the br tags consistently look like '</br'>, it's simpler and faster to use page.replace('</br>', ' ') instead. Otherwise, a regular expression might be more appropriate, as @minocha suggested. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5668962

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `some_string.replace('<br />','\n')` to replace the breaks with newlines.

```
>>> print 'Some data<br />More data<br />'.replace('<br />','\n')
Some data
More data
```

You might want to check out [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/) and [lxml](http://lxml.de/), which are both pretty great at parsing html. lxml is really fast and html5lib is designed to be extremely robust.

Comment: What if I have `<br class="fancy-break" />` in the HTML? Just a thought.

Comment: Using the `re` module would make more sense then. That's fairly unusual though.

Comment: I was just wondering if `beautifulsoup` parsed *only* tags or did the attributes only. Maybe piping this into a HTML/XML parser would work too? But if the OP *only* has `<br />`, then it's all good ;)