# Some tough string manipulation in Python

Tags: python, string, replace

I have this string in Python:

```
s = "foo(a) foo(something), foo(stuff)\n foo(1)"
```

I want to replace every foo instance with its content:

```
s = "a something, stuff\n 1"
```

The string s is not constant and the foo content changes every time. I did something using regex, split and regex, but got a very large function. How can I do it in a simple and concise way? Thks in advance.

Comment: `s.replace("foo", "a something, stuff\n 1")`

Comment: What values of x are allowed inside `foo(x)`? Are parentheses allowed, i.e. `foo(hello (there))`? If not, this should be simple with capturing groups

Comment: Nick ODell: foo content changes every time. it's unknown.

Comment: matt b: Great question. Does not allow parentheses. It allows identificators (essentially word)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> x = "foo(a) foo(something), foo(stuff)\n foo(1)"
>>> re.sub(r'foo\(([^)]*)\)', r'\1', x)
u'a something, stuff\n 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that the content of foo doesn't contain parentheses, Regex really doesn't seem  needed. Why don't you just do:

```
>>> s = "foo(a) foo(something), foo(stuff)\n foo(1)"
>>> s = s.replace('foo(','')
>>> s = s.replace(')','')
>>> print s
'a something, stuff\n 1'
```

See [Python: string.replace vs re.sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668947/python-string-replace-vs-re-sub)