# Remove special chracters from a string in django

Tags: python, django

I want to remove all special characters from email such as '@', '.'  and replace them with 'underscore'
there are some functions for it in python '**unidecode**' but it does not full fill my requirement . can anyone suggest me some way so that I can find the above mention characters in a string and replace them with 'underscore'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use `.replace()` ?

eg.

```
a='testemail@email.com'
a.replace('@','_')
'testemail_email.com'
```

and to edit multiple you can probably do something like this

```
a='testemail@email.com'
replace=['@','.']
for i in replace:
  a=a.replace(i,'_')
```

Comment: but replace takes only two arguments txt.replace('@','_' ) what if I want to remove more then one character

Answer (score 1):

Take this as a guide:

```
import re
a = re.sub(u'[@]', '"', a)
```

**SYNTAX:**

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, max=0)
```

Comment: Hi Cathy, replace is more fast than sub

Comment: thanks and it works but in opposite way...it is replacing **email@gmail.com** to **"""""@"""""."""**

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668947/python-string-replace-vs-re-sub)

Comment: @Jonathan  yes it works , but replace takes only two arguments **txt.replace('@','_'  )**  what if I want to remove more then one character

Comment: Depending on what @Inforian wants to do, rather than specify a character class containing "special" characters, it might be easier to specify a negated character class of "non-special characters". For instance, if we define a "special character" as anything that isn't a Roman letter or number, then something like `re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '_', email)`, should transform `an-example@example.com` into `an_example_example_com`.

Answer (score 1):

Great example from Python Cookbook 2nd edition

```
import string
def translator(frm='', to='', delete='', keep=None):
    if len(to) == 1:
        to = to * len(frm)
    trans = string.maketrans(frm, to)
    if keep is not None:
        allchars = string.maketrans('', '')
        delete = allchars.translate(allchars, keep.translate(allchars, delete))
    def translate(s):
        return s.translate(trans, delete)
    return translate


remove_cruft = translator(frm="@-._", to="~")
print remove_cruft("me-and_you@gmail.com")
```

output:

```
me~and~you~gmail~com
```

A great string util to put in your toolkit.

All credit to [the book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007973.do)