# Replace some special chracters from email in django

Tags: python, django, special-characters

I want to replace special characters from email in django. I have Google this issue and found stack question which is very helpful [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747459/remove-special-chracters-from-a-string-in-django).

But there are some issues with this. If i tried this

```
a='testemail@email.com'
    replace=['@','.']
    for i in replace:
        a=a.replace(i,'_')
```

or this

```
u_name=re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '_', str(email))
```

and in template

```
{% for i in u_name%}
{{i}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

it will return

```
t
e
s
t
e
m
a
i
l
_
e
m
a
i
l
_
c
o
m
```

but i want like this `testemail_email_com` so that i can store it in DB with the help of loop but it store only first characters.

So please tell me how i can do this.

Thanks

I am migrating some data from other DB and wanted to store it into django db. Let say i have data for 1o users , the emails of these users store into following array. Now i wanted to replace special characters from these email so that i can use them as username.

**Edited :**

```
email.append(row[i][1])
```

Answer (score 1):

If `u_name` is a single string, you can just use this:

`{{u_name}}<br>`

You're iterating through each character of the string - i.e.

```
>>> for i in "mystring":
    print i


m
y
s
t
r
i
n
g
```

---

As per your edit:

If `emails` is the name of your array, you need to replace each element, then print it:

```
>>> emails = ["me@apple.com", "you@test.com"]
>>> emails = [re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '_', x) for x in emails]
>>> print emails
['me_apple_com', 'you_test_com']
```

Then use template:

```
{% for email in emails%}
{{email}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: No u_name is an array and i have to replace all email that are under email array

Comment: @user1746291 It's not in your example though - you're clearly iterating through each letter. Could you show some more code? Where does the array come from?