# Regex search and replace substring in Python

Tags: python, regex

I need some help with a regular expression in python.

I have a string like this:

```
>>> s = '[i1]scale=-2:givenHeight_1[o1];'
```

How can I remove `givenHeight_1` and turn the string to this?

```
>>> '[i1]scale=-2:360[o1];'
```

Is there an efficient one-liner regex for such a job?

UPDATE 1:
my regex so far is something like this but currently not working:

```
re.sub('givenHeight_1[o1]', '360[o1]', s)
```

Comment: Are you going to post *your* regex? Also, where did `_1` go?

Comment: Have you tried the simple string.replace? s.replace("givenHeight_1","360")

Comment: As @user3203010 mentions, `string.replace` seems better here. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668947/use-pythons-string-replace-vs-re-sub

Comment: @user3203010 Well that did the job! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use positive `look around` with re.sub :

```
>>> s = '[i1]scale=-2:givenHeight_1[o1];'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=:).*(?=\[)','360',s)
'[i1]scale=-2:360[o1];'
```

The preceding regex will replace any thing that came after `:` and before `[` with an `'360'`.

Or based on your need you can use `str.replace` directly :

```
>>> s.replace('givenHeight_1','360')
'[i1]scale=-2:360[o1];'
```

Comment: I just did a simple replace as @user3203010 also suggested however I'm accepting this one for completeness and the `look around` trick.