# str.replace() or re.sub() continually until substring no longer present

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, str-replace

Let's say I have the following string: `'streets are shiny.'` I wish to find every occurrence of the string `'st'` and replace it with `'ts'`. So the result should read `'tseets are shiny'`.

I know this can be done using `re.sub()` or `str.replace()`. However, say I have the following strings:

1. `'st'`
2. `'sts'`
3. `'stst'`

I want them to change to `'ts'`,`'tss'` and `'ttss'` respectively, as I want all occurrences of `'st'` to change to `'ts'`.

What is the best way to replace these strings with optimal runtime? I know I could continually perform a check to see `if "st" in string` until this returns `False`, but is there a better way?

Comment: I think loop until no change is made is the only option, since the result of the replacement cannot be re-used with one and the same regex object.

Comment: @hwmd I was asking for anycase not just the examples I gave.

Comment: Please remember I'm hoping to optimise runtime.

Comment: Since `'st'` and `'ts'` have the same length, you can achieve the best performances using `bytearray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the looping solutions are probably the simplest, you can actually write a `re.sub` call with a custom function to do all the transformations at once.

The key insight for this is that your rule (changing `st` to `ts`) will end up moving all `s`s in a block of mixed `s`s and `t`s to the right of all the `t`s. We can simply count the `s`s and `t`s and make an appropriate replacement:

```
def sub_func(match):
    text = match.group(1)
    return "t"*text.count("t") + "s"*text.count("s")

re.sub(r'(s[st]*t)', sub_func, text)
```

Comment: If the OP intends to call it many times, it will make sense to use [``re.compile``](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile). That'll make it faster in the benchmark. @Blckknght: Perhaps you should add another solution to your answer using ``re.compile()``.

Answer (score 4):

I think that a while loop that just checks if the `'st'` is in the string is best in this case:

```
def recursive_replace(s, sub, new):
    while sub in s:
        s = s.replace(sub, new)
    return s

tests = ['st', 'sts', 'stst']
print [recursive_replace(test, 'st', 'ts') for test in tests]
#OUT:  ['ts', 'tss', 'ttss']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a pretty simple while loop:

```
s="stst"
while('st' in s):
  s = s.replace("st", "ts")
print(s)
```

> ttss

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continually check, then the other questions work well (with the problem that if you have something like `stt` you would get `stt`->`tst`->`tts`). I don't know if want that.

I think however, that you are trying to replace multiple occurences of `st` with `ts`. If that is the case, you should definitely use [`string.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace). .replace replaces every occurrence of a str, up to the extent you want.

This should be faster according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668947/use-pythons-string-replace-vs-re-sub).

`string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])`

example:

```
>>>import string
>>>st='streets are shiny.streets are shiny.streets are shiny.'
>>>string.replace(st,'st','ts')
#out: 'tsreets are shiny.tsreets are shiny.tsreets are shiny.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Naively you could do:

```
>>> ['t'*s.count('t')+'s'*s.count('s') for s in ['st', 'sts', 'stst']]
['ts', 'tss', 'ttss']
```