# How to chain multiple re.sub() commands in Python

Tags: python, regex, fluent-interface

I would like to do multiple re.sub() replacements on a string and I'm replacing with *different* strings each time.

This looks so repetitive when I have many substrings to replace. Can someone please suggest a nicer way to do this?

```
stuff = re.sub('__this__', 'something', stuff)
stuff = re.sub('__This__', 'when', stuff)
stuff = re.sub(' ', 'this', stuff)
stuff = re.sub('.', 'is', stuff)
stuff = re.sub('__', 'different', stuff).capitalize()
```

Comment: @Rawing, cool thanks that's better. My search wasn't showing that since I had re.sub(). Will delete.

Comment: Wait, actually should I keep this q since it's worded differently or delete it because it's a duplicate?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think it's worth keeping. But if you don't want to delete it, you can also close it as a duplicate.

Comment: @JTFouquier See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668947/use-pythons-string-replace-vs-re-sub

Comment: Yes, I will just use str.replace() instead. SO won't let me close this. ha.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Store the search/replace strings in a list and loop over it:

```
replacements = [
    ('__this__', 'something'),
    ('__This__', 'when'),
    (' ', 'this'),
    ('.', 'is'),
    ('__', 'different')
]

for old, new in replacements:
    stuff = re.sub(old, new, stuff)

stuff = stuff.capitalize()
```

Note that when you want to replace a literal `.` character you have to use `'\.'` instead of `'.'`.

Comment: I'm assuming it has been defined before, just like in the original code.

Comment: But `re.sub` hasn't been called before. `stuff` is just the original string at the beginning.

Comment: Ah, your right. I misread the OP's post. For some reason my brain replaced "stuff" with "string" ... and _now_ looking back at my answer, I still see it was pretty dumb. For the OP's use case, yours is clearly better. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

```
tuple = (('__this__', 'something'),('__This__', 'when'),(' ', 'this'),('.', 'is'),('__', 'different'))

for element in tuple:
    stuff = re.sub(element[0], element[1], stuff)
```