# Spacing and pattern replacement

Tags: python, spacing, punctuation

It is two part question:

**Part 1**

To remove multiple white spaces, paragraph breaks to just one.

**current code:**

```
import re
# Read inputfile
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file :
  inputfile = file.read()

# Replace extras spaces with single space.
#outputfile = re.sub('\s+', ' ', inputfile).strip()
outputfile = ' '.join(inputfile.split(None))

# Write outputfile
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
  file.write(outputfile)
```

**Part 2:**

Once the extra spaces are removed; I search and replace pattern mistakes.

Like:  ' [ ' to ' ['

```
Pattern1 = re.sub(' [ ', ' [', inputfile)
```

which throws an error:

raise error, v # invalid expression
error: unexpected end of regular expression

Although. This works...(for example: to join words together before and after hyphen)

```
Pattern1 = re.sub(' - ', '-', inputfile)
```

I got many situations to handle with respect to punctuation problem after spacing issue is solved.

I don't want patterns to look into the output of previous pattern results and move further.

Is there a better approach to cut spaces around punctuation to just right.

Comment: Why are you using regex find and replace when what you want to do is a simple string replace? the character `[` has a meaning in regex, same goes for `-`.

Comment: Yes you are right. Could have used str replace. But, speed wise, which is more faster?

Comment: Usually regex is magnitude slower  (in most programming languages). See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668947/use-pythons-string-replace-vs-re-sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, you can split it by newline blocks, compress each line, and then join it back on newlines, like so:

```
import re
text = "\n".join(re.sub(r"\s+", " ", line) for line in re.split("\n+", text))
print(text)
```

For the second part, you need to escape `[` since it's a regex metacharacter (used to define character classes), like so:

```
import re
text = re.sub("\[ ", "[", text)
text = re.sub(" ]", "]", text)
print(text)
```

Note that you don't need to escape the `]` because it doesn't match a `[` so it isn't special in this context.

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##hY6xbsMwDER3fQXByUYLLZ2z9wMCdLA9KDELq1VIgWKQ5OtdKXWKoksJSSBwd@@Ub7YIv6yr0dVgB5KJO/SR89m8RcFnQMXeK4W5613WyNY172PH3fdg7@IpixoouQ2GI6P/kMidki/nQ6c4lqeGhPqkyNTDu@h9g8jQXDnFCh252e49/5RuVVsBjkND4/BI/9VhavL0I/9ir@srpSQwwJtommFy@yUWqCdUczFXZ7@QEoR6TQROgW/AdGn/L86FVASsZQ4ajp9kFbWEGmeofA1QcjhSw8wUElyiLRANpi8)

Alternatively for the second part, `text = text.replace("[ ", "[").replace(" ]", "]")` because you don't even need regular expressions.