# Fastest way to update a character in a string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have to replace every '%' character with '%%' in a string and as string are immutable i am doing `list(string)` and then replace every '%' with '%%'.
But string can be huge(len(string)>2000) and as a result list can be huge that can slow down so i want to know the fastest way to do that in python 2.7

Comment: use `some_var.replace('%', '%%')` function

Comment: Strings are immutable in Python. Your best bet is `.replace`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use replace method on string?
Use the following code

```
a = "hello %"
print(a.replace("%","%%")
```

There is one more way to this, and that is to use Regex. but, go through [This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668947/use-pythons-string-replace-vs-re-sub) to know why string replace method is preferred over regex