# Remove a big list of of special characters

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove each of the following special characters from my documents:

```
symbols = {`,~,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),_,-,+,=,{,[,],},|,\,:,;,",<,,,>,.,?,/}
```

The reason why I am not simply doing something like this:

```
document = re.sub(r'([^\s\w]|_)+', '', document)
```

is that in this way I remove also many (accented/special) letters in the case of documents written in languages such as Polish etc.

How can I remove each of the special characters above in one expression?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh, thank you for your answer but I do not know what this exactly means. Can you please give me an example or a complete answer to my question?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh, it can be any text which has some of these special characters too (as many texts do). You can very easily create one by yourself.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh no confusion will occur - let's not waste time - the others below have already given an answer. If you cannot come up with any text (how difficult is it?) then take this: `(Hello World)] *!` which should be `Hello World`

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this without regular expressions by using [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
symbols = {"`", "~", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "-", "+", "=", "{", "[", "]", "}", "|", "\\", ":", ";", "\"", "<", ",", ">", ".", "?", "/"}

for c in symbols:
    document = document.replace(c, "")
```

Comment: To be honest, I am finally thinking about using `.replace()` than regular expressions for the reasons mentioned here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668947/use-pythons-string-replace-vs-re-sub

Comment: @PoeteMaudit, you should apply regex in situations when it's really needed. In this particular situation you there's another solutions. You can also check benchmarks in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27086669/10824407) answer.

Comment: Of course but the problem is that I am not sure when regex are really needed. Any specific advices please? To be very honest with you I am not sure what is the point of regex while .replace() exists but on the other hand I see many people using the former.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit, there's [some usefull tips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5670379/10824407).

Comment: By the way, since you are open to answer these question, why not use str.translate() in this case? Again the same question with regexs, when to use str.translate() and when to use str.replace()?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of the symbols you want to remove, you can construct this simple regex:

```
rgx = '|'.join(map(re.escape, symbols))
```

**Example:**

```
# example symbols list
symbols = ['"', '<', '+', '*']

document = '<div prop="+*+">'

rgx = '|'.join(map(re.escape, symbols))

document = re.sub(rgx, '', document)

print(document)
```

**Output:**

```
div prop=>
```

The code `'|'.join(map(re.escape, symbols))` will construct the following regex:

```
\"|\<|\+|\*
```

which means match any one of the symbols `"`, `<`, `+`, or `*`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
symbols = ['a', 'b', '|']
document = document.translate({ord(c):None for c in symbols})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove literally each character, you can use `str.replace` and [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html?highlight=string#string.punctuation) module:

```
a = '345l,we.gm34mf,]-='

for char in string.punctuation:
    a = a.replace(char, '')
a
```

> `'345lwegm34mf'`

If you need more symbols to replace (`string.punctuation` equals to `'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'`), you can add them to a`in` string.

Answer (score 0):

without re:

```
"".join(str(x) for x in document if x not in symbols)
```