# How to add suffix to a plain text in python

Tags: python, dictionary, suffix

I have the following text that I want to send by mail. I have to convert it to html, therefore to each line separator I have to add 
.

How can I do it in such a way that it fits me?
Here is my attempt.

```
text = """
Hi, my name is John,
Regards
"""

strString = map(lambda x: x + '<br>', text)
print(list(strString))
['\n<br>', 'H<br>', 'i<br>', ',<br>', ' <br>', 'm<br>', 'y<br>', ' <br>', 'n<br>', 'a<br>', 'm<br>', 'e<br>', ' <br>', 'i<br>', 's<br>', ' <br>', 'J<br>', 'o<br>', 'h<br>', 'n<br>', ',<br>', '\n<br>', 'R<br>', 'e<br>', 'g<br>', 'a<br>', 'r<br>', 'd<br>', 's<br>', '\n<br>']

Desired output
text = """
Hi, my name is John,<br>
Regards<br>
"""
text
'\nHi, my name is John,<br>\nRegards<br>\n'
```

Comment: Are you wanting to keep or remove the `\n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking to *replace* newlines

```py
>>> text = """
... Hi, my name is John,
... Regards
... """
>>> import re
>>> print(re.sub(r"\n", "<br>\n", text))
<br>
Hi, my name is John,<br>
Regards<br>
```

Alternatively, you can use `<pre>` ([preformatted text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)) to write out the text as-is! (though it's really more for code blocks and probably not appropriate for other text)

```html
<pre>
Hi, my name is John,
Regards
</pre>
```

As **PacketLoss** notes, if you only have a trivial character/substring to replace, using the `.replace()` method of strings is fine and may be better/clearer!

Comment: Just to note @Raymont for basic uses such as this, you should use `string.replace()` as there is no need to use `regex` here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668947/use-pythons-string-replace-vs-re-sub

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace all new lines `\n` with `<br>` you can simply use `string.replace()`

```
print(text.replace('\n', '<br>'))
#<br>Hi, my name is John,<br>Regards<br>
```

To keep the new lines, just modify your replacement value.

```
print(text.replace('\n', '<br>\n'))
<br>
Hi, my name is John,<br>
Regards<br>
```