# Extract letters (and a specific number) from a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a list of strings similar to the one below:

```
l = ['ad2g3f234','4jafg32','fg23g523']
```

For each string in `l`, I want to delete every digit (except for `2` and `3` if they appear as `23`). So in this case, I want the following outcome:

```
n = ['adgf23','jafg','fg23g23']
```

How do I go about this? I tried `re.findall` like:

```
w = [re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+',t) for t in l]
```

but it doesn't give my desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture 23 in a group, and remove all other digits. In the replacement, use the group which holds 23 if it is there, else replace with an empty string.

```
import re

l = ['ad2g3f234', '4jafg32', 'fg23g523']

result = [
    re.sub(
        r"(23)|(?:(?!23)\d)+", 
        lambda m: m.group(1) if m.group(1) else "", s) for s in l
]
print(result)
```

Output

```
['adgf23', 'jafg', 'fg23g23']
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/U0JONS)

Comment: could you explain what the lambda function is doing? thanks

Comment: @NewbieAF The lambda is the callback function for re.sub See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub where is this code example `m` is the 'matchobj'

Comment: The function checks if the match object has a capture group 1 which contains the value 23. If there is a capture group 1 present, then put back the 23. If there is no group 1 present, then the match contains all other digits except 23. That match is then replaced by an empty string.

Comment: How do I exclude more characters? For example, if I want to exclude “-“, “+”, “{}” and “()” as well as any digit not making “23”?

Comment: @NewbieAF The pattern does not match `-` or `+` so they will stay in the string.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be just to replace the string twice:

```
[re.sub("\d", "", i.replace("23", "*")).replace("*", "23") for i in l]
```

Output:

```
['adgf23', 'jafg', 'fg23g23']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a placeholder with [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
l = ['ad2g3f234','4jafg32','fg23g523']
w = [re.sub('#','23',re.sub('\d','',re.sub('23','#',t))) for t in l]

['adgf23', 'jafg', 'fg23g23']
```

**EDIT**

As answered by Chris, the approach is the same although **string replace will be a better alternative** [stack_comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668947/use-pythons-string-replace-vs-re-sub)

Answer (score 0):

Using re.sub with function

import re

```
def replace(m):
    if m.group() == '23':
        return m.group()
    else:
        return ''
    
l = ['ad2g3f234','4jafg32','fg23g523']
w = [re.sub(r'23|\d', replace, x) for x in l]

#w: ['adgf23', 'jafg', 'fg23g23']
```

**Explanation**

```
re.sub(r'23|\d', replace, x)
- checks first for 23, next for a digit
- replace function leaves alone match with 23
- changes match with digit to null string.
```